# Creating changesets when the key names of source struct differ from the column names of the schema?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

This seems to be a very easy problem to solve but apparently I haven't been able to think straight or look at the right place.

Say I have a schema, where columns are named in snake_case, by convention, e.g. `branch_id`.

Normally, if the data is coming from a Phoenix form, you'd have the keys of the data corresponding exactly to the keys of the schema, so that you can write `%MyStruct{} |> cast(attrs, [:branch_id])` etc.

However, in my JSON API, the incoming JSON object would have keys in camelCase, e.g. `"branchId"`.

Is there any function from `Ecto.Changeset` that I can use to conveniently correspond such keys from the incoming data to the columns in my schema?

An obvious solution would be to (in the controller,) `Enum.map` over the incoming JSON first, use `Macro.underscore` to convert the keys, and collect the result back into a map, before passing it to the `changeset` function. However that would seem to be really extraneous and inefficient.

This is not only limited to the situation of snake_case vs. camelCase, but potentially any situation where the key looks different from the intended column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing the client sending the JSON to your API, require that your API call JSON keys are snake_case to match the API endpoint.

The `Macro.camelize` and `Macro.underscore` functions are also not suitable for certain cases since they [do not support unicode or invalid-in-Elixir-identifier characters](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.html#underscore/1), so you may want to look into [Case2](https://hexdocs.pm/case2/Case2.html) if you want to accept camelCase and mutate into snake_case.

You could implement recase conditionally, e.g. if you receive a request with camelCase keys, `Enum.map` or `Enum.filter` and recase, but in most cases it is best to just spec your client API calls to match your backend API endpoints

Edit: changed Recase ref to Case2 since Recase apparently can't handle unicode either :P

Comment: Sure. Unfortunately in this case I can't really change the incoming data, but it also seems that in Ecto every column has to be in snake_case. I just thought that `Enum.map` would be quite inefficient and wonder if there's a way in Ecto itself to do it.

Comment: FYI: turns out `Recase` does not support Unicode as well, so I created [`Case2`](https://hexdocs.pm/case2/Case2.html#content) package with full Unicode support. It shows nearly the [same performance](https://github.com/am-kantox/case2#basicbench) as ASCII-only `Recase`.

Comment: @xji I wouldn't worry too much about manipulating key strings, since if Ecto had a function for doing key string manipulation it'd probably still have to do the same kind of mutation under the hood -- just avoid creating :atoms dynamically and you should be fine @Aleksei Interesting about Recase, replaced with a ref to your `Case2` package.